# PATH environment variable content on Compute Engine with different SSH access commands

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When I login to through the cloud ssh in the browser, I can type in the following and get the following results:

```
yewenpu@instance-beef1:~$ whoami
yewenpu
yewenpu@instance-beef1:~$ which python
/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
```

When I try to use the gcloud sdk command line through terminal from local machine, I get something different

```
evan@evan-box:~$ gcloud compute ssh --zone=us-east1-b yewenpu@instance-beef1 --command='whoami; which python'
yewenpu
/usr/bin/python
```

so is my name same but different? what's going on here? adding "source .bashrc" to the command didn't do anything.

Comment: Could it that when you add the "--comand" you aren't running your local .profile or .bashrc?   See if you can't find where /opt/anaconda3/bin is being added to your PATH in the first example ... that might give us a clue.

Comment: wait that sounds very useful except i have no idea what you're saying. can you be a lot a lot more detailed? @Kolban

Comment: http://www.theunixschool.com/2011/07/what-is-profile-file.html
https://www.maketecheasier.com/what-is-bashrc/
https://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them

Comment: the two approaches have the same .bashrc file, which leads me to believe they're the same ? same ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a work-around. I do not know why it works. The idea is just to brute-force export the path to where python is

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone=us-east1-b yewenpu@instance-beef1 --command='export PATH=/opt/anaconda3/bin:$PATH; echo $PATH; whoami; which python'

/opt/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games
yewenpu
/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
```